# Keyboard shortcut for "find in page"

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm keybinding some shortcuts and I just want to know what the "find in active window" command is, ie the Ubuntu equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Windows.

Comment: You mean in nautilus? You can directly search by typing in the active window. You don't need a shortcut.

Comment: I don't think it's recognizing my ctrl-f. For example in text, ctrl-f doesn't invoke the search toolbar.

Comment: I mean, in Nautilus you can search for a file or a folder just by typing. When you press a key a search bar will appear automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Each application has set their keybindings separately, for example:

- Gnome-terminal uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for the search function. (only text)
- gedit uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (only text)
- nautilus uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (only files)
- Others applications have set their own keybinding.

There isn't a central option to set such keybindings, the same happens in Windows ecosystems. Most of them are hard coded and are (almost) impossible to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Most software has a find option mapped to Ctrl+F. Others such as the terminal are mapped to Ctrl+Shift+F.

Comment: The program's aren't recognizing my ctrl-f

Comment: Could it be either a hardware or keyboard selection issue?

Comment: But every other ctrl - [ ] works for applications.